# splitting Sitemap into more sitemaps if it has more than maxnumber of urls

Tags: java, xml, sitemap

I would like to split my Sitemap into Sitemaps, if it has more than `maxURLs`. The following example should split the Sitemap, if it has more than one url.

```
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.CharacterData;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.StringReader;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class SiteMapSplitter {

    public static void main(String[] args){

            String sitemapStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n" +
                    "<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">\n" +
                    "<url>\n" +
                    "<loc>test1.html</loc>\n" +
                    "<lastmod>today</lastmod>\n" +
                    "<changefreq>daily</changefreq>\n" +
                    "<priority>1.0</priority>\n" +
                    "</url>\n" +
                    "<url>\n" +
                    "<loc>test2.html</loc>\n" +
                    "<lastmod>yesterday</lastmod>\n" +
                    "<changefreq>daily</changefreq>\n" +
                    "<priority>1.0</priority>\n" +
                    "</url></urlset>";
            try {
                splitSitemap(sitemapStr);
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        static private void splitSitemap(String sitemapStr) throws ParserConfigurationException {

            DocumentBuilder db = null;
            try {
                db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(sitemapStr));

            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = db.parse(is);
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("url");

            int maxURLs = 1;
            Set<String> smURLsSet= new HashSet<String>();
            if (nodes.getLength()>maxURLs){
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                    StringBuilder smURLsBuilder = new StringBuilder("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n" +
                            "<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">\n");
                    for (int k = 0; k<maxURLs; k++){
                        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                        smURLsBuilder.append(element);
                    }
                    smURLsSet.add(smURLsBuilder.toString());

        }
                Iterator i = smURLsSet.iterator();
                while(i.hasNext()){
                    System.out.println(i.next());
                }
            }

    }

    }
```

The problem is that   `Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i); smURLsBuilder.append(element);`

does not append the whole element (in this case the `url` and its childreen) to the `smURLsBuilder`. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using an object oriented approach to the sitemap. Either with data binding (JAXB) or even shorter using [data projection](http://xmlbeam.org) (Disclosure: I'm affiliated with that project). This way you do not need to create the XML by string concatenation.

```
public class SitemapSplitter {

    static String sitemapStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n" +
            "<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">\n" +
            "<url>\n" +
            "<loc>test1.html</loc>\n" +
            "<lastmod>today</lastmod>\n" +
            "<changefreq>daily</changefreq>\n" +
            "<priority>1.0</priority>\n" +
            "</url>\n" +
            "<url>\n" +
            "<loc>test2.html</loc>\n" +
            "<lastmod>yesterday</lastmod>\n" +
            "<changefreq>daily</changefreq>\n" +
            "<priority>1.0</priority>\n" +
            "</url></urlset>";

    public interface Sitemap {
        @XBWrite("/urlset/url")
        Sitemap setUrls(List<? extends Node> urls);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        XBProjector projector = new XBProjector(Flags.TO_STRING_RENDERS_XML);
        // Get all urls from existing sitemap.
        List<Node> urlNodes = projector.onXMLString(sitemapStr).evalXPath("/xbdefaultns:urlset/xbdefaultns:url").asListOf(Node.class);
        for (Node urlNode: urlNodes) {            
            // Create a new sitemap, here with only one url
            Sitemap newSitemap = projector.onXMLString(sitemapStr).createProjection(Sitemap.class).setUrls(Collections.singletonList(urlNode));
            System.out.println(newSitemap);
        }       
    }
}
```

This program prints out

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>test1.html</loc>
<lastmod>today</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
</urlset>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>test2.html</loc>
<lastmod>yesterday</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: how to make it for variable urls?

Comment: My example uses `Collections.singletonList(urlNode)` to create a `List` with one URL. If you like to have 3 URLs, you need to create other instance of `List` (e.g. LinkedList) and fill it with 3 URLs before you call `setUrls(...)`with your list. Does this help?

Comment: I have added the dependency <dependency>
    <groupId>org.xmlbeam</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlprojector</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.6</version>
</dependency><dependency>
    <groupId>org.xmlbeam</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlprojector</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.6</version>
</dependency>  and tried your code. I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jcr/Node

Comment: you need to import `org.w3c.dom.Node`, not `javax.jcr.Node`

Comment: thank you. When I install my osgi with this feature I get the following error in the imported packages: org.xmlbeam -- Cannot be resolved
org.xmlbeam.annotation -- Cannot be resolved
org.xmlbeam.evaluation -- Cannot be resolved

Comment: Can you try Require-Bundle instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70468/discussion-between-cfx-and-ronald).